# collectEntries keys not being found

Tags: groovy

I'm using collectEntries to build a map from a different map. However when I try to get the values based on the keys. It returns null, even though when I print the entire map the key is there.

```
static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, List<String>> multiMap = ['apple': ['granny', 'delicious']]
    Map m = multiMap.collectEntries { String k, List<String> v ->
        v.collectEntries { String subkey -> ["${k}-${subkey}": subkey] }
    }

    println m
    println m.keySet()
    println m['apple-granny']
    println m[m.keySet()[0]]
}
```

The output is:

```
[apple-granny:granny, apple-delicious:delicious]
[apple-granny, apple-delicious]
null
null
```

Why can't I retrieve the value from the map? How should I be doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your key is a GString instance, not a String..  ([See](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39045417/groovy-strings-vs-java-strings/), [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31713359/why-are-there-different-behaviors-for-the-ways-of-addressing-gstring-keys-in-map), [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591036/odd-behaviour-with-map-in-groovy/), [on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705492/why-groovy-does-not-see-some-values-in-dictionary/), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39141245/why-map-does-not-work-for-gstring-in-groovy), [about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22186392/why-does-groovy-map-key-evaluation-behave-differently-in-similar-circumstances-w) this issue)

Change your collectEntries line to:

```
    v.collectEntries { String subkey -> [("${k}-${subkey}".toString()): subkey] }
```

To force the key as a String and it will work fine